# Q-ships as a solution to steath in space, how do you get back out?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space-warfare

Given that stealth in space is [likely impossible](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacewardetect.php#nostealth), how could you design a [Q-ship](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/pirate.php#id--Q-Ships) that could carry out operations that require stealth? The idea here is about building a warship that is disguised as a civilian vessel for covert operations.

The big problem I see is that while deception probably works as a substitute for stealth as a means of getting there without problems, it would never let you get back out. How could this be achieved?

There are also a few assumptions that have to be the case here. Obviously this would require that space trade is common enough for your hidden warships to avoid too much scrutiny. I'm also assuming highly efficient engines like [Torchships](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/torchships.php#id--What_is_a_Torchship?), which requires that everything in space be monitored for traffic control and safety reasons regardless of military concerns, and that some kind of orbital patrol organization has the ability to intercept ships for safety reasons. The military situation is a Cold War like scenario within the solar system.

Comment: What is a Q-ship and what is a Torchship?

Comment: A Cold War...but with enough frequent trade to hide warships? Wouldn't each side try to curtail trade? And what's the need for Q-ships in a COLD war?

Comment: @Daron i am equally as confused

Comment: Surely the point of a Q-ship is as a decoy, why would you hide a decoy?

Comment: I would recommend that you check out the ThoughSF blog. It is similar to Atomic Rockets, but significantly less conservative. Maybe they are too optimistic sometimes, however they have a fairly well founded "Stealth in Space is Possible" series and a number of interesting stealth craft designs like the Hydrogen Steamer and ATOMSS.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight The problem I have with hydrogen steamers is that they are impossible to make fast. They are plausible enough as a technology, but they are generally far too slow when compared with torchships. The idea here was about building something that would be fast enough to operate at a reasonable pace when compared with military or commercial craft.

Comment: Okay, so...a "Q-ship" is some kind of fishing vessel with a gun on it and a "torch ship" is "kind of vague". Please, forget dubious sources and just explain what you mean!

Comment: I don't think that slow (stealth) craft would be out of place in a setting with torch ships. If speed were the only thing that mattered in war, we today would send ICBM barrages at the enemy and be done with it. No Army required. However, the army and the Hydrogen steamer offer a unique set of skills. Anonymously blowing up enemy positions or picking up agents is quite valuable.  Just maintain several vessels across the system on standby to activate them when you need one. Unless torch drives are almost cost-free, slow vessels won't disappear. An ore freighter has litte t gain from speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your covert operation remains covert.**

A Qship refers to a dangerous / military / armed vessel disguised as a merchant vessel.  The question asks how such a vessel gets to the site of interest and then gets back out.  Answer: as a merchant vessel.

For example: tractor trailer comes from Mexico loaded with kitty litter.  One barrel of kitty litter is actually a large bomb.  Drivers come across the border, cargo checked, duly waved on.  Drivers drop off a load of kitty litter, drop off another load of kitty litter, drop off the bomb, drop off last of the kitty litter as bomb goes off across town.  Then they load up on cardboard for recycling and go back across the border.

A Qship need not be entirely a decoy.  It helps with the decoy piece if in some respects you actually are what you appear to be.  If I am a spy who claims to be a pleasure traveler in Kazakhstan to see the sights, I had better actually go see the sights.  If I stay covert, I might be able to leave the way I came in, as a pleasure traveler now with a suitcase of Kazakh souvenirs.